# what is a Kernel?

Tags: kernel, system-calls

I'm learning Unix from the Unix Architecture book by Maurice J Bach.

My confusion is with the concept of kernel. What is a kernel? I understand it's the operating system and it is a process.

But when my teacher teaches he says a system call(), results in a process going from user mode to kernel mode.

What actually happens in a system call? Does the user process go to sleep and the  operating system execute it on behalf of user process and returns the value to the user process or does the user process execute in kernel mode?
If the latter is correct, what does it mean?

Comment: I suggest you read a basic intro text such as William Stalling's "Operating Systems" (or go through his slides available on the net) http://williamstallings.com/OperatingSystems/ .

Comment: Explanation too big? k will try his slides

Comment: Yep, in essence, the kernel is the "core" part of the operating system that runs at a higher privilege level than the "user mode" programs -- even those that are part of the operating system. So, in Linux e.g. the init script is user mode but device drivers are kernel mode. You can do with first few chapters of the slides to get this.

Comment: went through slides of chapter 2 still no help :(

Comment: I believe a long sit down with your teacher, to provide insight and ultimately options into your future, is also a valid - and maybe even simpler - course of action.

Comment: @illuminÉ: The fact that it's November means the OP has probably been studying this for a few months now, and is still confused. An extra hour with the prof probably isn't going to help. What the OP needs is many hours of reading and experimentation. Thus my answer, which really is just a series of pointers to proper answers.

Comment: @Warren Young - I hear you. My comment is not a reaction to your answer.

Comment: Nope don`t think Question can be reworded @illuminÉ what do you mean by "options into your future"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is a kernel?

In the sense of your question, it is a single large program that runs at a special privilege level on the processor. It provides all of the core operating system facilities: [multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitasking), [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem), etc. It is also the process that runs the [device drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver), which in turn control the computer's hardware on behalf of the kernel.

> I understand it's the operating system

Actually, no. An [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is much more than just the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29).

Even back in the days when Maurice Bach was writing his book, the OS included [shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29), [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_software), [text editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor), etc.

Over time, the term OS has come to include even more things, like the [GUI subsystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).

It's a personal decision where you draw the line between the OS and normal user programs. Most people would agree that a GUI word processor is not part of the OS even if it was installed along with the OS proper. But, many would also agree that the plain text editor that came with the OS *is* part of the OS. Many in that camp would also agree that the [markup processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) that come with the OS — troff, TeX, etc. — are also considered OS facilities these days. But combine a text editor and a markup processor, and you have something indistinguishable from a word processor in some ways.

Drawing a stark line that everyone can agree on in impossible.

> it is a process.

Not really, no.

A [microkernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) architecture is as close as you're going to get to making that statement true. Even then, the kernel is a *collection* of processes, one of which is special in that it is the one that can run all of the *other* processes. So even in that case, there is still a core — a tiny kernel — that cannot itself be said to be a normal process.

In the case of a [monolithic kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel), the kernel is in a special position, and it *runs* all of the processes.

> What actually happens in a System call?

Read the rest of Bach's book.

You will notice that this answer has many Wikipedia links, and most of the articles I link to are long and complicated, with many more links leading off. This is because you've basically asked us to distill a very complicated topic into a simple answer. There is not a simple answer, so I have tried to provide a *guide* to the answers, plural.

> Does the user process go to sleep and the operating System Executes it on behalf of User process and returns the value to user process…?

In a classic monolithic kernel as discussed by Bach, yes.

Modern systems fuzz this simple picture, though.

First, the "operating system" doesn't execute the system call, the kernel does. I am not just being pedantic. Since the huge bulk of a modern OS is composed of assorted user-space programs, and modern OSes are multitasking, you can't say that the OS just stops and runs the system call. The OS may be doing many things at the same time, *one* of which is handling a single user program's system call.

But second, and this is much more important, modern OS kernels are no longer single-tasking programs that handle one system call at a time. An OS may be in the middle of *many* system calls at once. A single-tasking user space program that makes a system call may *perceive* that the world stops until the system call finishes, but the kernel may be doing many other things while that system call proceeds.

Even in the case of an old-style single-tasking kernel, you had things like driver [top- and bottom-halves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler), which allowed the kernel to go off and handle things like disk I/O in order to provide low-level service to a relatively high-level system call like `open(2)`.

> or the user process executes in kernel Mode?

You could look at it that way, but it's only true in the same sort of way that my web browser and Stack Exchange are the same program because they are interoperating to provide a single cohesive experience.

Comment: hi Thanks for replying So u have summed saying Kernel mode and Kernel Executing on behalf of user process(while user process sleeps)are the same correct is my undertsanding correct or have i misunderstood u r answer

Comment: @AAB: On Stack Exchange, the only true thanks is an upvote. :)

Comment: I know but I don`t seem to have enough reputation and as for my understanding of u r answer is it  wrong or correct

Comment: @AAB: As for your new question, it's sorta kinda correct, but it's natively phrased. Read up on [asynchronous I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_io) and you might get some idea of what I mean here. When a program sets up an async I/O call, the kernel is handling the system call *at the same time* that the user process continues running. That is, the user process might *not* have to sleep through all system calls. Or, consider [signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal), which may be sent during a system call.

Comment: In Design of Unix Operating system book by Maurice J Bach let me Quote from the book "The Kernel is not a Separate Set of Processes that run in Parallel to user processes,but its part of each user process." could you explain what this line means ? its on page 16 below fig 1.5

Comment: The author is attempting to distinguish a monolithic kernel design from a microkernel design. Read those Wikipedia articles, linked above. Also, keep in mind that the sentence was written in the mid-1980s, when OSes were much simpler than they are today. (That's why the book is still valuable, by the way: because it describes a simpler world.) With modern systems, the OS kernel is more isolated from user processes than it was in classic Unix systems.

Comment: I don`t seem to have enough reputation for that as well :P Thank You for Time Warren if i Have any difficulties will comment.