# What is a Kernel Routine ?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, man

In another answer I met a short overview of the sections of the man pages:

1. commands for $-User
2. system call, that means evoking a function from the Kernel
3. library call, that means evoking a function from a conventional file
4. special files
5. conventions and configuations
6. games
7. miscellanous
8. commands for #-User

Now mostly there were mentioned these 8 sections, but a few times there was also mentioned a 9.th section:

9. kernel routine

What is the very meaning of a Kernel Routine, what is its purpose within the operating system ?

Answer (score 1):

The Linux-based system I tried doesn't have a section 9 in its man page, but, looking online, one can find the [NetBSD intro(9) man page](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?intro+9+NetBSD-current):

```
This section contains information related to the internal operation of
the system kernel.  It describes function interfaces and variables of use
to the systems and device driver programmer.
```

This appears to be about APIs provided by the kernel.

Answers to the following questions may be relevant: [what is a Kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101396/88983)